# Построить столбчатую диаграмму с временем по оси y

Tags: python, matplotlib

Из своей программы выделил этот кусок для описания проблемы:

Необходимо построить график с барами, где по оси 'y' отложено время от 00:00 до 23:59, 'x' -- условно имена людей в виде цифр (оси получились, см. первый скрин).[image: получившиеся оси]

На графике должны корректно откладываться наборы временных отрезков, например,

- от 00:00 до 01:00, от 01:00 до 12:00 для "1",
- от 00:00 до 00:30, от 00:30 до 16:00 для "2"

(см. второй скрин).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Если** раскомментировать последние строки с `"plt.bar="`, то получатся такие ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ВОПРОС:** Объясните, пожалуйста, как и в каком формате задавать наборы данных для 'y', чтобы они отображались правильно?

```
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import timedelta

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

min_lim = np.datetime64('2005-02-03 00:00')
max_lim = np.datetime64('2005-02-03 23:59')
lims = (min_lim, max_lim)
plt.ylim(lims)

hours = mdates.HourLocator(interval=1)
h_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')

ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(h_fmt)

plt.xlim(-0.5, 3.5)


x = np.arange(1, 2)

y11 = timedelta(hours=2, minutes=30)
y12 = timedelta(hours=2, minutes=0)
y21 = timedelta(hours=1, minutes=30)
y22 = timedelta(hours=3, minutes=0)

series1=[y11, y12]
series2=[y21, y22]


#plt.bar(x, series1, color='r', bottom=0)
#plt.bar(x, series2, color='g', bottom=series1)
plt.show()
```

Сразу говорю, я прогуглил весь интернет. С matplotlib'ом и его непонятной документацией у меня дикие проблемы, особенно после qt (где все чудесно понятно, спасибо QtРебята!).

ДУБЛИРУЮ ВОПРОС:

> **ВОПРОС:** Объясните, пожалуйста, как и в каком формате задавать наборы данных для 'y', чтобы они отображались правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно сначала привести ваши timedelta в формат datetime, чтобы matplotlib мог с ними работать. В вашем конкретном примере можно сделать так:

```
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

min_lim = np.datetime64('2005-02-03 00:00')
max_lim = np.datetime64('2005-02-03 23:59')
lims = (min_lim, max_lim)
plt.ylim(lims)

hours = mdates.HourLocator(interval=1)
h_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')

ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(h_fmt)

plt.xlim(-0.5, 3.5)


x = np.arange(1, 2)

y11 = min_lim.astype(datetime) + timedelta(hours=2, minutes=30)
y12 = y11 + timedelta(hours=2, minutes=0)
y21 = min_lim.astype(datetime) + timedelta(hours=1, minutes=30)
y22 = y21 + timedelta(hours=3, minutes=0)

series1=[y11, y12]
series2=[y21, y22]


plt.bar([1,2], [series1[1], series2[1]], color='g')
plt.bar([1,2], [series1[0], series2[0]], color='r')
plt.show()
```

получите, соответственно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]